# Is LAZY mode really used in production?

Tags: jpa

The more I progress in JPA technology, the more I think LAZY mode specially for Collections is not a good solution, I think it can be replaced by namedQueries.
Am I right ?

Comment: A lazy collection is just syntactic sugar for not needing to have explicit queries and help modeling JPA entities the OO way - I use this since at least 10 years, so from the view of all the projects I did in the past, you are definitely wrong :-)

Comment: You are probably right, but I am obliged to use Hibernate.initialize(customer.getOrders()) to get orders after accessing customer, so my application is dependant from Hibernate ! How do I do if I migrate to Toplink ?

Comment: As long as you are inside of a transaction you can access all collections without initializing them - also, it is advisable to properly think of system boundaries so transaction have a limited lifespan and duration. I usually advise my colleagues to stick to JPA standard classes and not use Hibernate specifics to stick to the JEE spec.

Comment: Hi, I have understood why I had problems with LAZY Loading, my application is an Enterprise Application witch have an EJB module (EJB Entity and EJB Session) and a Web module (servlets, jsp views ...) and these two modules don't work in the same container. Are you agree with me ?

Comment: If they don't work in the same container, how do they work together?

Comment: I'm not comfortable enough to explain how they communicate, but they do. Here's a link that might be interesting : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html